# Accessing abstract class properties from extended class

Tags: dart, oop, abstract-class

Having this snippet:

```dart
abstract class SuperClass {
  static String id = 'id';

  static String get getId {
    return id;
  }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
  static String name = 'name';
}

void main() {
  print(SubClass.name);
  print(SubClass.id);
}
```

How can i access `id` property?

`print(SubClass.id);` results in error:

**"line 3 • The getter 'id' isn't defined for the type 'SubClass'."**

Doesn't `SubClass` should inherit the `id` property when extended (not implemented)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Dart, static methods and properties are not inherited.

This is covered in section 10.7 of [the Dart language spec](https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.10.pdf):

> 10.7 Static Methods staticMethods
> Static methods are functions, other than getters or setters, whose declara-
> tions are immediately contained within a class declaration and that are declared
> static. The static methods of a class C are those static methods declared by C.
>
> Inheritance of static methods has little utility in Dart. Static methods cannot
> be overridden. Any required static function can be obtained from its declaring
> library, and there is no need to bring it into scope via inheritance. Experience
> shows that developers are confused by the idea of inherited methods that are not
> instance methods.
>
> Of course, the entire notion of static methods is debatable, but it is retained
> here because so many programmers are familiar with it. Dart static methods
> may be seen as functions of the enclosing library.
>
> Static method declarations may conflict with other declarations (10.10).

Other References

- [Dartlang GitHub issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/368)
- [Google Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/g/misc/c/dudRfe0YSyo)
- [What's the rationale behind not inheriting static variables, in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20215820/3558355)
- [Dart Patterns to replace static inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20726598/3558355)
- [How can I inherit static methods in dart/flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71471938/3558355)

Comment: Super, thank you. What if that properties were not static? Would that be a possible case?

Comment: @MikeV. I'm not clear what you're asking. If you're asking if non-static methods and properties are inherited, then yes.

Comment: Yeah, that was the point. Thank you!